# Unwanted space before/after trace using go.Scatter with markers

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm using graph objects in plotly and I'm using `go.Scatter` to create line traces. However, when `mode='lines+markers'`, space is created before and after the start/end of the trace. This does not happen when `mode='lines'` only. The graph is dynamic based on input so I can't just enter a static range, is there any way to have the markers and eliminate space aside from determining the min_x and max_x range as a variable.

```py
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dff['datetime'], y=dff['y1'], fill='tozeroy', 
                         mode='lines+markers'), 
              secondary_y=False)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dff['datetime'], y=dff['y2'],
                         mode='lines'), 
              secondary_y=True)
```

[image]

```py
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dff['datetime'], y=dff['y1'], fill='tozeroy',
                         mode='lines+markers'), 
              secondary_y=False)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dff['datetime'], y=dff['y2'],
                         mode='lines+markers'), 
              secondary_y=True)
```

[image]

Unwanted space is indicated in red above.

Comment: I can't explain why that would be the case, If you specify the minimum and maximum x-axis values in the data frame, you don't have to go to the trouble of making them variables. Try this: `fig.update_xaxes(range=[dff['datetime'].min(), dff['datetime'].max()])`